# SERIESSUM for large N

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to calculate the sum of the formula

`P=POWER((1-p);(N-1))*p` for N=1 to 83,332.

I did it using **SERIESSUM** but I needed **83,332** cells with the same value (p) to include them as coefficients.

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it in Excel...

Comment: This might be a dumb question but what actually is the "p"?

Answer (score 1):

Credit for this answer goes to this site: https://exceljet.net/formulas/create-array-of-numbers

You can create array of numbers artificially by using ROW and INDIRECT like so:

(This will create an array of integers from 1 to 83332)

```
=(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A83332")))
```

This is an array formula so if you want to use it, you need to press **ctrl-shift-enter** when entering it into a cell.

for your example, you could do:

```
=SERIESSUM((1-D11);1;1;CEILING.MATH(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A83333"))/83333)*p)
```

Just replace "p" with whatever you need it to be and don't forget to press **ctrl-shift-enter** when entering the formula.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't explain myself well.
The formula P=POWER((1-p);(N-1))*p has to be calculated for N=1 to N=83,333 and added up.
Btw, p is constant.
I did it with SERIESSUM((1-D11);1;1;coef.!B2:B83334) but I needed the same number (p) repeated 83,333 times in lines B2 to B83334 (in sheet "coef.") to be entered as 83333 coefficients.
I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without having 83333 times repeated the same number.

Comment: @Boris Hey, thank you for the explanation. I edited my answer with a solution that should work for your example.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!